# Signalr: Client in asp.net mvc connect to external server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I need to connect my web application on a server SignalR. This server is being accessed by a Windows Phone application and works as it should. What I need to do is access via the Web application and send a message to this phone windows application that is connected on the other side.

I want to communication via Controller for there must notify anything on the web site screen for the user.

**Server Startup.cs:**

```
internal class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            try
            {
                app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

                ConfigureGlobalHost();
                var configuration = new HubConfiguration
                {
                    EnableDetailedErrors = true,
                    EnableJSONP = true
                };

                app.MapSignalR("/signalr", configuration);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //Log.AddMessage("An error occurred during server configuration: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public void ConfigureGlobalHost()
        {
             GlobalHost.Configuration.ConnectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
             GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
             GlobalHost.Configuration.TransportConnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
             GlobalHost.Configuration.DefaultMessageBufferSize = 500;
        }
```

}

**ConnectionHelper:**

```
public class HubConnectionHelper : IDisposable
{
     public IHubProxy HubProxy { get; set; }
     public HubConnection Connection { get; set; }
     private string _serverURI;

     public HubConnectionHelper(string nomeDoHub, string urlServicoCentral)
     {
         _serverURI = string.Format("http://{0}:8080", urlServicoCentral.Split(':')[0]);

         Connection = new HubConnection(_serverURI);
         Connection.TransportConnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);

         Connection.Closed += Connection_Closed;

         HubProxy = Connection.CreateHubProxy(nomeDoHub);
     }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(ConfiguracaoTerminalViewModel cTerminal)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          var loja = _lService.ObterLoja();
          if (_cTerminalService.Gravar(new ConfiguracaoTerminal
          {
               Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
               CaminhoServidorEmissao = cTerminal.CaminhoServidorEmissao,
               NumeroEletronico = cTerminal.NumeroEletronico,
               Serie = cTerminal.Serie,
               LojaId = cTerminal.LojaId,
               TerminalId = cTerminal.TerminalId,
               AmbienteNFe = cTerminal.AmbienteNFe
          }))
          {
               await _cTerminalHub.NotificarTerminal(cTerminal.TerminalId.ToString(),
                                              "Configuração inserida com sucesso.\n\nFim das configurações.");
               return RedirectToAction("Index");
          }
     }
     return View(cTerminal);
}
```

**Server hub:**

```
public class ConfiguracaoTerminalHub : Hub, IDisposable
{
    private readonly SignalRConnectionService _signalRConnectionService;
    private readonly TerminalService _terminalService;

    public ConfiguracaoTerminalHub()
    {
        _signalRConnectionService = new SignalRConnectionService();
        _terminalService = new TerminalService();
    }



    public void NotificarTerminal(string connectionId, string message)
    {
        Clients.Client(connectionId.ToString()).ReceberNotificacaoConfiguracaoTerminal(message);
        Console.WriteLine("Notificação enviada do Retaguarda para um terminal pendente.");
    }


    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        SalvarConexao(Guid.Parse(Context.Headers.Get("terminalId")));
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        ExcluirConexao(Guid.Parse(Context.ConnectionId));
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }
```

**EDIT:**

*ConfiguracaoTerminalHub (clientside, use for connect):*

```
public class ConfiguracaoTerminalHub : IDisposable
{
    public ConfiguracaoTerminalHub(string urlServidor)
    {
          _conHelper = new HubConnectionHelper("ConfiguracaoTerminalHub", urlServidor);
     }

     public async Task NotificarTerminal(string connectionId, string message)
     {
          await _conHelper.Connection.Start(); //the error occurs here
          await _conHelper.HubProxy.Invoke("NotificarTerminal", connectionId, message);
     }
}
```

Error:

```
 StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1,
 Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
 {
     Date: Tue, 12 Jan 2016 12:57:51 GMT
     Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
     Content-Length: 0
}
```

Comment: what is `_cTerminalHub` and where is it initialized?

Comment: @ZoharPeled It is initialized in the constructor. I have this class to use with the same name as the Hub is in signalr server. This facilitates the organization as separate them by names which communicates.I edited the question with the code.

Comment: Shouldn't `_conHelper` be a class member of the `ConfiguracaoTerminalHub` class? From the code you provided I would expect a null reference exception.

Comment: @ZoharPeled the error is not a Null reference exception... the error occurs in: await _conHelper.Connection.Start();

Comment: @ZoharPeled the _conHelper is a HubConnection but configured.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I can help at this point. perhaps someone else might be able to help you.